# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 with CocoaLumberjack and ZXingWidget

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, zxing

I've integrated the ZXing QR Code reader library (ZXingWidget) into my iPhone app, but it conflicts with a function from within the CocoaLumberjack logging library that I am also using.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"ExtractFileNameWithoutExtension(char const*, signed char)", referenced from: ...

DDLog.h
NSString *ExtractFileNameWithoutExtension(const char *filePath, BOOL copy);

#define THIS_FILE (ExtractFileNameWithoutExtension(__FILE__, NO))

DDLog.m
NSString *ExtractFileNameWithoutExtension(const char *filePath, BOOL copy) { ...
```

As I call it in:

```
DDLogVerbose(@"%@:%@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
```

The cause for this is that whichever Obj-C file contains the headers:

```
// import QR Code reader APIs
#import "ZXingWidgetController.h"
#import "QRCodeReader.h"
```

its file extension must be changed from **.m** to **.mm** for proper C++ support.

But then I lose my *DDLogVerbose(@"%@:%@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);* functionality.

What am I missing here to have these two play nice with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're including C headers that aren't "C++-ified" into a C++ or Objective C++ file, you need to tell the compiler. Something like

```
extern "C" {
#include "DDlog.h"
}
```

in your `.mm`s should work. Alternatively, if `DDLog.h` is your file, you can do something like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
NSString *ExtractFileNameWithoutExtension(const char *filePath, BOOL copy);
```

A web search for "extern C" should provide more details/examples.

Comment: OF COURSE! geez, this brings me back to my Turbo C++ days.  #ifdef __cplusplus method worked it out.  Thank you. :)